# NSButton setEnabled not working

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, interface-builder, nsbutton

I am trying to start  an application with every button disabled except for one. First of all, I've tried to set them to disabled through the interface builder and then set them to enabled when I need them to be enabled.  However, when I call setEnabled: it doesn't actually enable them (I even did NSLogs to see if it was getting there!). Secondly, I also tried to initialize them to be disabled in the code (within the applicationDidFinishLaunching: method) and then once again set them to enabled, but that still didn't work.  Does anybody have a suggestion to try and make them disabled/enabled when I need them to be?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
     [loadImageButton setEnabled:NO];
     [autoFitButton setEnabled:NO];
     [estimateAgeButton setEnabled:NO];
     [ageProgressButton setEnabled:NO];
}


- (IBAction)loadAAMModel:(id)sender
{
   ...
   ...
     if (waam.ModelLoaded) {
         [modelNameLabel setStringValue:f];
         [svmLabel setStringValue:svmPath];
         [ageTableLabel setStringValue:ageTable];
         NSLog(@"model loaded...set loadImageButton to Enabled!");
         [loadImageButton setEnabled:YES];
         NSLog(@"loadImageButton set to Enabled.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing should work. I'm going to guess that the references to your buttons are `nil`. You can verify this by putting a line like:

```
NSLog(@"loadImageButton = %@", loadImageButton);
```

in `applicationDidFinishLaunching:`.

Perhaps you just neglected to wire them up in Interface Builder.

Comment: wow…that makes twice i've done that today…not hooked them up to the controller! i linked methods to them but other than that i didn't hook them up. thanks for recognizing my stupidity! :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean **DISABLED** or **UNSELECTED**?

If disabled, you will not be able to interact with the button (i.e. no action will result from touching it) until you set them back to `setEnabled:YES`

If selected, it means your BUTTON will be assigned a selected control state (`UIControlStateSelected`). To change its selected state, all you have to do is

```
[button setSelected:(BOOL)];
```

If you could please paste the code where you are initialising the button and setting its properties it will be easier to identify what you might be doing wrong.